# Exporting Redmine issue tags into PDF

Tags: ruby, pdf, tags, export, redmine

I'm using Redmine with [redmine_tagging](https://github.com/Restream/redmine_tagging) plugin. There is an option for creating PDFs in issue's view. I would like to customize the exported PDF to show the tags of the issue.
I've already found out the helper class for exporting PDFs, so I can now customize most of output fields but not the tags. [Here](https://insight.io/github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/lib/redmine/export/pdf/issues_pdf_helper.rb) is the ruby source code of a general Redmine's helper.
For example this is how I write out the status:

```
left << [l(:field_status), issue.status]
```

I've found out how to show label for tags:

```
left << [:Tags, ???]
```

However, the values of tags are 'missing'. I assume it should be some kind of array, as if I make a query on issues with a rest client I get json like this:

```
{
"issues": [
  {
   ...
   "tags": [],
   },
   ...
}
```

Any idea?
Thank you!

Comment: StackOverflow is for discussing specific code; see [ask]. This will likely be closed. I recommend that you experiment with the [RBPDF](https://github.com/naitoh/rbpdf) gem, which Redmine uses, and see if you can add text to a PDF. If you have trouble, post the specific code you're having problems with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem this way:

```
    context = TaggingPlugin::ContextHelper.context_for(@project)   
    affected_issue = Issue.find(issue.id)
    issue_tags = affected_issue.tag_list_on(context)
    tagsString = ""
    issue_tags.each do |x|
        tagsString += " " + x.to_s
    end

    left << [:Tags, tagsString]
```